# ошибка при чтении xlsx через pandas.read_excel

Tags: python, pandas

возникает ошибка `AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'getiterator'` при
следующем вызове:

```
from pandas import read_excel

df = read_excel('t2.xlsx', sheet_name='2019')
```

как можно решить эту проблему?

версии установленных модулей:
`pandas==1.1.3`
`xlrd==1.2.0`

весь стэк вызовов приводящий к ошибке:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyCharm projects\snakeBox\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    df = read_excel('t2.xlsx', sheet_name='2019')
  File "C:\\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 296, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 304, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 867, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 22, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 37, in load_workbook
    return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 130, in open_workbook
    bk = xlsx.open_workbook_2007_xml(
  File "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 812, in open_workbook_2007_xml
    x12book.process_stream(zflo, 'Workbook')
  File "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 266, in process_stream
    for elem in self.tree.iter() if Element_has_iter else self.tree.getiterator():
AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'getiterator'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете попробовать использовать параметр engine="openpyxl". Мне это помогло решить аналогичную проблему.

Comment: не знаете в чем проблема xlrd сломанный на новый версиях что ли или с pandas что-то? просто до этого работало, переустановил перестало работать, поставил старые версии этих модулей все равно не работает

Comment: Подозреваю, что проблема в неподдержке новой мажорной версии python.